# Math Inequality using induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

Prove that $\log_3\pi + \log_\pi 3 > 2$ without using log tables.

I was thinking of using strong induction for something like this, but I find it a difficult thing to come by, especially giving the lack of variables. How does one generally approach a problem like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: use change of base so your inequality has the form $x+\frac{1}{x}>2$, and then use the AM-GM inequality. (This obviously has nothing to do with induction.)

Answer (score 4):

Clearly $\pi\ne3$, so
$$(\ln\pi-\ln3)^2>0\ .$$
Expanding and taking the middle term to the RHS,
$$(\ln\pi)^2+(\ln3)^2>2(\ln\pi)(\ln3)\ .$$
Dividing both sides by $(\ln\pi)(\ln3)$ gives
$$\frac{\ln\pi}{\ln3}+\frac{\ln3}{\ln\pi}>2\ ,$$
and the "change of base"  formula gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

By using change of base formula and AM-GM inequality we have
$$\log_3\pi+\log_{\pi}3=\frac{\ln \pi}{\ln 3}+\frac{\ln 3}{\ln \pi}> 2\sqrt{\frac{\ln \pi}{\ln 3}\frac{\ln 3}{\ln \pi}}=2$$